# Fit a switch to rectifier input or output?

Tags: switches, mains, rectifier

I have a set of LED fairy lights. The cable has an AC/DC rectifier between the mains plug and the LEDs. I want to fit a single pole switch so I can turn the lights on or off without having to use the switch on the mains socket. Should I switch the rectifier input (i.e. fit the switch between the mains plug and the rectifier) or switch the rectifier output (i.e. fit the switch between the rectifier and the LEDs)? If it makes no difference, is there a convention to follow? Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't break anything on the DC side after the rectifier!  Demonstraion video here: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Zez2r1RPpWY

Fit your switch on the input/AC side.

Comment: Yes the issue with LED's is you dont know the reactance or switched load reactive effects and plasma arc voltage  Cuttoff voltage  is higher with no AC zero crossing current.  Hence the big gap before arc stops. But if you know there is no inductor, then either side dont care

Comment: +1 for cool video... I can't see it doing that with a string of LEDs though, regulator is probably a low constant current source. But..... you never know. Some other question the person switched the AC side and there was a distinct delay compared to the switch on the DC side that came with the string.

Comment: @Trevor Yes, it is load dependent but even at 220 V, the breaking becomes a huge challenge. Houses has burned down due to arcing on DC over a breaker or fuse. The delay is much easier to live with ghan a fire.

Comment: @winny, yes indeed, hence my "you never know" statement.

Comment: Makes you wonder how all the mechanical relays people seem to love to use on here ever work huh...

Comment: @Trevor They all switch either AC or low voltage DC.